# How to pass a variable as a temporary file to a command in bash

Tags: bash

There exists a command `foo` which expects two arguments which are filenames and which prints some stuff on stdout.

I have a Bash script with two variables `a` and `b` holding two strings.

I wish to pass to `foo` two filenames where the contents of those files are `a` and `b`. I then want to store the stdout as a new variable `c`.

Following ad hoc Googling, the script would perhaps look something like:

```
a=...;
b=...;
c=`foo <($a) <($b)`;
```

What *should* it look like?

Comment: Depending on how `a` and `b` are set in the first place, you can replace `<($a)` with `<( cmd-that-sets-a )` and skip the variables altogether.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=...
b=...
c=$(foo <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b"))

echo "$c"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work where `$a` or `$b` have newlines in them.

Comment: Make sure you quote `"$c"` if you print it out. `echo "$c"` not `echo $c`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `echo -e`

```
a=...
b=...
c=$(foo <(echo -e "$a") <(echo -e "$b"))

echo -e "$c"
```